# Canvacord .setBackground Error: Server responded with 526

Tags: discord, discord.js

So I have a rank command for my XP system and I want to add a custom background to the rank card i keep getting the error Error: Server responded with 526, when i try .setBackground

```
if(command === "rank") {
    const target = message.mentions.users.first() || client.users.cache.get(args[0])|| message.author
    if (!target) {
    target = message.author;
    }        
    const user = await Levels.fetch(target.id, message.guild.id);
    const neededXp = Levels.xpFor(parseInt(user.level) + 1);
    
    if(!user) return message.channel.send('Keep talking you dont have any xp');
    const rank = new canvacord.Rank()
    .setAvatar(target.displayAvatarURL({dynamic:true, format: 'png'}))
    .setCurrentXP(user.xp)
    .setLevel(user.level)
    .setRequiredXP(neededXp)
    .setRank(parseInt(user.position))
    .setBackground("IMAGE", "https://cdn.hipwallpaper.com/i/18/33/2YI0rO.jpg")
    .setStatus(target.presence.status)
    .setProgressBar("#40e0d0", "COLOR")
    .setUsername(target.username)
    .setDiscriminator(target.discriminator)
    rank.build()
    .then(data =>{
        const rankcard = new Discord.MessageAttachment(data, 'rankcard.png')
        message.channel.send(rankcard)
    })
    .catch(console.log);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(command === "rank") {
    const target = message.mentions.users.first() || client.users.cache.get(args[0])|| message.author
    if (!target) {
    target = message.author;
    }        
    const user = await Levels.fetch(target.id, message.guild.id);
    const neededXp = Levels.xpFor(parseInt(user.level) + 1);
    const background = 'https://cdn.hipwallpaper.com/i/18/33/2YI0rO.jpg'
    
    if(!user) return message.channel.send('Keep talking you dont have any xp');
    const rank = new canvacord.Rank()
    .setAvatar(target.displayAvatarURL({dynamic:true, format: 'png'}))
    .setCurrentXP(user.xp)
    .setLevel(user.level)
    .setRequiredXP(neededXp)
    .setRank(parseInt(user.position))
    .setBackground("IMAGE", background)
    .setStatus(target.presence.status)
    .setProgressBar("#40e0d0", "COLOR")
    .setUsername(target.username)
    .setDiscriminator(target.discriminator)
    rank.build()
    .then(data =>{
        const rankcard = new Discord.MessageAttachment(data, 'rankcard.png')
        message.channel.send(rankcard)
    })
    .catch(console.log);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).